# Moment.js .isBefore comparing dates with a time zone offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

The two moments that need to be compared are:

1. today now in a certain time zone (Wed Oct 12 2016 08:42:19 GMT+0000)
2. A selected date from a calendar (e.g. 2016-10-11)

   Here is how I am working it:

```js
var date = '2016/10/12'; // october 11                
var offset = '0'; // time zone offset in minutes, 0 = GMT
var dateToday = moment().utcOffset(offset); // get a moment now with the time zone offset
var selectedDate = moment(date, ["YYYY-MM-DD"]).utcOffset(offset); // and a moment that is the date of the day selected

alert(dateToday);
alert(selectedDate);

if (selectedDate.isBefore(dateToday, 'day')) {                                   
  alert('That date is in the past!');
} else {
  alert('Great!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

The problem appears to be that because I am in Paris time (+02:00) any offset that I select below Paris time(+02:00) for example GMT (+00:00) then that sets the select date -1 day in the past at 10:00PM.

So my question is how do I correctly check to see if a date (2016-10-12 GMT) is in the past?

**UPDATE:**

I have solved it for now by extracting the date, regardless of timezone, using the format function. Then I created brand new moments passing the date strings explicitly into those moments like this:

```js
var dateToday = moment().utcOffset(offset);      // get a moment now with the time zone offset
var selectedDate = moment(date, ['YYYY-MM-DD']); // and a moment that is the date of the day selected

var dateToday    = dateToday.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var selectedDate = selectedDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

var dateToday    = moment(dateToday, ['YYYY-MM-DD']);
var selectedDate = moment(selectedDate, ['YYYY-MM-DD']);
```

Comment: Moment by default parses dates in local timezone. I think that you can just remove the offset part from your code and everything will work fine. Otherwise you can compare your string in UTC using [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/). If you need to use multiple timezone maybe you can use [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: Only problem is when I select a time zone that is -XX:00 GMT their date might be one day in the past... for example right now it could be the 11th in Pacific/Pago_Pago, but the script is validating dates that are the 12th GMT. I need to account for that. I am trying to do this purely with moment.js because time-zone.js requires me to upload a list of time zones, I just feel that is a contrived solution when I already have that list (with offsets) from PHP. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting the selectedDate hours and minutes 00:00 or assigning an offset to it ?

```
var date = new Date();
var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * (-1)
selectedDate.add(offset, "hours");
```

Comment: Solved it, probably not the best solution but it will work for the 'moment'. If anyone is interested in the solution check out the OP edit.